# python pandas: How to simplify the result of groupby('column_name').count()

Tags: python, pandas

quick one, imaging we have a df which contains Walmart's global sales contacts, say, 20 columns. What I want to do is every simple: figure out how many rows there are for each country. Naively, I will do :

```
df.groupby('country').count()
```

but this will return a table of 20 columns, which are identical for each column. Is there a way to just show the result as a 2-column table? i.e, country and counts?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `value_counts()`:

```
pd.value_counts(df.country)
```